# SUM loop in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible such aggregation in BigQuery? I have two fields – datetime and value(float64). Every 10 minutes one value is posted in table:

```
-----------------------------------
| datetime              | value   |
-----------------------------------
| 2018-11-01T09:00:05   | 1.1     |
| 2018-11-01T09:10:01   | 1.2     |
| 2018-11-01T09:20:59   | 2.4     |
| 2018-11-01T09:30:18   | 0.8     |
| ...                   | ...     |
| 2018-11-21T22:50:04   | 2.1     |
| ...                   | ...     |
| 2018-11-30T23:59:59   | 4.2     |
-----------------------------------
```

Is there a way to get aggregated table with date and sum of all previous values from beginning till particular date included? 
E.g. for one month it would be 31 (or 30) date rows and value row for each day would have sum of all previous values:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| date                  | value                                       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2018-11-01            | SUM of all values 2018-11-01...2018-11-01   |
| 2018-11-02            | SUM of all values 2018-11-01...2018-11-02   |
| 2018-11-03            | SUM of all values 2018-11-01...2018-11-03   |
| 2018-11-04            | SUM of all values 2018-11-01...2018-11-04   |
| ...                   | ...                                         |
| 2018-11-20            | SUM of all values 2018-11-01...2018-11-20   |
| ...                   | ...                                         |
| 2018-11-30            | SUM of all values 2018-11-01...2018-11-30   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL - you first group by day and sum all values for the day and then you apply windowed function to get final result

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  day, SUM(value) OVER(ORDER BY day) value
FROM (
  SELECT DATE(dt) day, SUM(value) value
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY day
)
```

In case if you need to "reset" sum each month - you can use below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  day, SUM(value) OVER(PARTITION BY DATE_TRUNC(day, MONTH) ORDER BY day) value
FROM (
  SELECT DATE(dt) day, SUM(value) value
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY day
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it work as expected. Great "reset" feature!

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery CTEs usually help make things easier to understand. This should work in case of your `datetime` values:

```
with datevals as (
  select date(datetime) as date, sum(value) as value from `dataset.table` group by 1
)
select a.date as dt, sum((select sum(b.value) from datevals b where b.date <= a.date )) as value
from datevals a
group by 1
order by 1
```